# Fuji Nevada 1.5 29er (2017) - 549$ or Trek Marlin 7 (2018) - 375$ (discount)?

Tags: mountain-bike, commuter, hybrid-bike, trek, heavy

Fuji Nevada 1.5 29er (2017) - 549$ or Trek Marlin 7 (2018) - 749$? Below are the URLs

I am 6'3, 285lbs

Trek - Marlin 7 | Trek Bikes (https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bike ... 7/p/17382/)

Fuji - Fuji Nevada 1.5 29er Mountain Bike - 2017 (https://www.performancebike.com/shop/fu ... 17-31-6286)

I am looking for a bike for a daily commute (paved road/foot path) and may be trails but definitely not mountain biking. I commute 20 miles a day and this is my first bike.

I am leaning towards the mountain bike because I thought they will handle my weight better.

Can something like this handle the above scenario? (https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/hybrid-bikes/dual-sport-bikes/ds-series/ds-3/p/17205/?colorCode=black)

Comment: Sorry but we don't do product recommendations. However, going from zero to 20 miles a day is a _huge_ and, honestly, infeasible jump. Put it this way: I'm a relatively keen cyclist and do a 30-mile ride most weekends; I did 64mi recently. I live about 3mi from work and my normal route in is about 6mi, because exercise and nicer route. When the weather's nice, like today, I have a few other routes of about 10mi. If I'm tired or I'm late or it's windy and definitely if it's raining, I'm _not_ going to pick a 10mi route. But you're proposing to do the 10mi route every day, _and_ back home.

Comment: Start with a used bike - don't jump into a new one.  Once you get a year on an older bike, you'll have a better idea of what works for you.  The junkiest walmart full-suspension used bike will be super cheap, and no  big loss if you break it.   And in the future when you test new non-suspension bikes, they will feel even better.  There's a good chance you'll loose some weight over a year of biking too.

Comment: Thank you. I bike 10 miles every other day on a stationary bike in the gym. This will be my first bike doing commute on roads.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments specific product recommendations are off topic here. (See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Answering the question about suitability of the bikes you link to for the commuting you want to do:

A mountain bike at this price point would not be a good choice for commuting on paved roads or paths. The forks are low-end and basically add nothing but weight. You would be better off with a hybrid, city or commuter bike with a rigid fork but with clearance for fairly wide tires, at least 40mm.

The groupsets on these bikes are also possibly a bit low end for regular commuting. They will work, but be prepared to deal with frequent adjustments and replacing worn parts.

With regards to your weight, at this price point a mountain bike is not really any more sturdy than a hybrid, city or commuter bike. I believe weight limits are around 135kg / 300lbs which will accommodate you, but you may find you have problems with the wheels going out of true or breaking spokes.

Comment: +1 for making the answer agnostic.

Comment: @Criggie Thx. There is often an on topic aspect to a product rec question

Comment: I am sorry. I will keep in mind not to ask about product recommendations.

Comment: @Venkata Sagar Varma Godavarthi No problems, it's a 'mistake' many new users make. It's not that we don't want to be helpful, it is because recommendations are highly subjective and become outdated quickly.

Comment: Definitely a mistake. This was my first question and I didn't know that it was something that shouldn't be asked.

Comment: Also I wanted to ask, would a hybrid bike serve my purpose or should I lean towards the mountain bike?